# Why should $a^n=e$?

Tags: group-theory

> If $G$ be a finite cyclic group generated by $a$ and order of $G$ is $n$ then why should $a^n=e$ ?

Starting with $G={e,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}}$ now $a^n$ must be equal to one of the elements of $G$ but why $e$ ?

Comment: Do you know what "order" means?

Comment: Look up the definition of "order".

Comment: That is the definition of the order of an element.

Comment: How does that help ? Could u plz elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Did you in fact look up the definition you were asked to?

Comment: Order of element $g$ is $n$ if $g^n=e$ !

Comment: Do you mean in the question, that $G$ has order $n$? Then the question makes sense: We want to show that the generating element then has order $n$. I can write an answer for that.

Comment: @tobias i have edited my question a bit,now can you help ?

Comment: For the same reason a cat should be a feline.  The *definition* of the order of $a$ is $n$ is that $a^n =e$ (and $n$ is the smallest such value).  So it equals $e$ because that is what "order" means.  If $a^n \ne e$ then we wouldn't say the order of $a$ is $n$.

Comment: Ok, now the question makes more sense to me. The general answer would be "Lagrange", but the answer by JG also works here since the group is cyclic.

Comment: @fleablood , i am not saying order of $a$ is $n$ ,i am saying order of $G$ is $n$

Comment: That's... the same thing. The order of an element $a$ is the smallest $n$ so that $a^n=e$.  A quick lemma is that no two $j <k\le n$ can have $a^j=a^k$ as that would mean $a^{k-j}=e$ but $n$ was the smallest such positive integer. And the cyclic group $G=<a>$ is al the elements of $ a^1..., a^{n-1},e=a^n$.  Such a group  must have all distinct $n$ elements and no others.  So the order of the cyclic group and the order of the generator are the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with $a$ and go to $a^n$ 
$$\{a,a^2,a^3,...,a^n\}$$
These are distinct elements so one of them must be $e$

If it is some $a^k$ for $k<n$ then the order of group will be $k$ which is less than $n$

Comment: You r the only one ,who gave the relevant answer to my need,as i am following gallian ,i haven't yet encountered the largranges theorem. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Comment: You actually haven't shown that they must be distinct, depending on how you define generator. I took "generator" to mean $\{a^m\mid m\in\mathbb Z\}=G.$ To show they your set must be distinct, you need that if $a^i=a^j$ with $i>j$ then $a^{i-j}=e$ and you get at most $i-j$ distinct elements in  $\{a^m\mid m\in\mathbb Z\}=G.$

Comment: Good point. Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 3):

**Definition 1:** If $G$ is a group and $a\in G$ then $\langle a\rangle = \{a^m\mid m\in\mathbb Z\}.$

**Definition 2:** A group $G$ is cyclic with generator $a\in G$ if $\langle a\rangle = G.$

---

**Lemma:** If $G$ is a group and $a\in G$ and $a^d=e$ for $d>0$ then there are at most $d$ elements in $\langle a\rangle.$

**Proof**: Given $m\in\mathbb Z,$ we apply the division algorithm so that $m=dq+r$ with $0\leq r<d.$ Then $$a^m = a^{dq}a^r=\left(a^d\right)^qa^r=e^qa^r=a^r$$

So $\langle a\rangle = \{a^0,a^1,\dots,a^{d-1}\}$ which has at most $d$ distinct elements in it.

---

**Theorem:** Given a cyclic group $G$ with $n$ elements and a generator $a\in G,$ then $a^n=e.$

**Proof:** In the set $\{a^0=e,a^1,a^2,\dots,a^n\}$ you must have $i,j$ with $0\leq i<j\leq n$ such that $a^i=a^j,$ otherwise there are $n+1$ distinct elements of $G.$

But then $a^{j-i}=e.$ By the lemma, then, $G=\langle a\rangle$ has at most $j-i$ elements. And $0<j-i\leq n.$ Since $G$ has $n$ elements, we get that $j-i=n$ which is only possible if $j=n,i =0,$ and thus $a^n=a^0=e.$

Comment: The great thing is ,the lemma has nothing to do with uniquness of elements,it just says there are *atmost $d$ elements* ,now using this if $a^i=a^j$ then group has to have *atmost $i-j$ elements* ,and hence the result.

Answer (score 2):

In the sequence $\{a^i\}_{i\ge0}$, there must be repetition since $G$ is finite, e.g. $a^k=a^l$ with $k>l$. Since all elements are invertible, $a^{k-l}=e$. Since some $n\gt0$ satisfies $a^n=e$, we call the minimum such $n$ that works for all $a$ the order of $G$. (It's at most the LCM of the values of $n$ for each $a\in G$.)

Comment: Is it the part of defination that" if $n$ is the smallest number such that $a^n=e$ then order of $G$ is $n$ "?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, it is true that if $G$ is any finite group with order $n$, then $g^n = 1$ for **any** element $g \in G$. This is true whether or not $G$ is cyclic or even abelian.

The order $o(g)$ of an element $g$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k$ = 1. This is the same as the order of the subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ generated by $g$. By Lagrange's theorem, this order must be a divisor of $|G| = n$. So we must have $n = km$ for some positive integer $m$. Then $g^n = g^{km} = (g^k)^m = 1^m = 1$.

Comment: That's true for any $a$ in any group, but this question is simpler - it assumes $G$ is a cyclic group and $a$ is a generator.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Understood, I just wanted to point out the more general fact. I edited to clarify this.

Comment: @Thomas can you tell me that *simpler* fact ?

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't  if the group is $\{e,a^1, a^2, ..., a^{n-1}\}$; then why does $a^n = e$.

The question is if $a^n=e$ and for $1\le m < n$ that $a^m \ne e$; then why is $\{a^1,a^2,....., a^{n}=e\}:=<G>$  a group.

See, the order of the group being $n$ came *from* $a^n =e$.  Not the other way around.

And it is a group because

i) the $a^i$ are distinct.

Pf: if $a^j = a^m$ but $1\le j< m\le n$ then $a^m=a^j*a^{m-j} = a^j$ so $a^{m-j} = (a^j)^{-1}*a^j*a^{m-j}=(a^j)^{-1}*a^m = (a^j)^{-1}*a^j = e$.  But $1\le m-j<n$ and $n$ was the smallest positive integer so that $a^n=1$.  $a^j \ne a^m$.

ii) The operation is closed.

Pf:  If $1\le j \le n$ and $1\le m\le n$ then $2\le j+k \le 2n$.  If $j+k \le n$ then $a^ja^k = a^{j+k}$.  If $j+k > n$ then $j+k - n \le n$ and $a^ja^k = a^{j+k} = a^{j+k-n}a^n =a^{j+k-n}*= a^{j+k -n}$.

iii) $e=a^n$ is in the set.

iv) every element has a an inverse in the set.

Pf:  If $a^m; m\ne n$ is in the set then $a^{n-m}$ is also in the set and $a^ma^{m-n} =a^n = e$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $a^n = a^k$, where $0\le k<n$. Then 
$$
a^{n-k} = e
$$ 
We know $a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ (corresponding to $k=n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$) are all distinct from $e$. So we must have $k=0$, i.e. $a^n=0$.